# Maximum Boxes in BoxStore

Tags: android, objectbox

After reading quickly ObjectBox docs, i am wondering how much Boxes can we create inside a given BoxStore ?

I am planning to create Boxes dynamically but do not want to exceed limitations if there are some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boxes are nothing that you create dynamically. For each entity type there's one instance max.